# iOS Bluetooth transfer get incomplete data sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

ios client get the incomplete data When the data send in very short intervals. but if the data send to ios client in a enough intervals has no problem. this is my codes, any suggestion？ Thanks :-)

```
- (void)handleIncoming:(NSInputStream *)stream
{
    while ([stream hasBytesAvailable])
    {
        unsigned char buf[DATA_CHUNK_SIZE];
        NSUInteger len;
        NSLog(@"hasBytesAvailable...............");
        len = [stream read:buf maxLength:DATA_CHUNK_SIZE];
        if(len > 0)
        {
            OppoDLog(@"raw len: %d", len);
            [appDelegate receivedData:buf length:len];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Time duration can be a issue,  if you're file is larger then 90k you'll have to break it up. Here is how I would suggest you break things up:

**1st - Send the name of your file**

```
NSData* fileNameData = [fileNameStr dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// send 'fileNameData'
```

**2nd - Send the number of chunks your going to send**

```
NSUInteger fiftyK = 51200;
NSUInteger chunkCount = (((NSUInteger)(srcData.length / fiftyK)) + ((srcData.length % fiftyK) == 0 ) ? 0 : 1))
NSString chunkCountStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",chunkCount];
NSData* chunkCountData = [chunkCountStr dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// send 'chunkCountData'
```

**3rd - Break up and send your NSData object into a set of NSObjects of less then 50k each (just to be on the safe size)**

```
NSData *dataToSend;
NSRange range = {0, 0};
for(NSUInteger i=0;i<srcData.length;i+=fiftyK){
  range = {i,fiftyK};
  dataToSend = [srcData subdataWithRange:range];
  //send 'dataToSend'  
}
NSUInteger remainder = (srcData.length % fiftyK);
if (remainder != 0){
  range = {srcData.length - remainder,remainder};
  dataToSend = [srcData subdataWithRange:range];
  //send 'dataToSend'  
}
```

On the receiving side you'll want to do the following:

**1st - Receive the file name**

```
// Receive data
NSString* fileNameStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

**2nd - Receive the number of chunks you are about to receive**

```
// Receive data
NSString* chunkCountStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
NSUInteger chunkCount = [chunkCount intValue];
```

**3rd - Receive the chunks of data**

```
NSMutableData data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<chunkCount;i++){
  // Receive data
  [data appendData:receivedData];
}
```

If everything has worked right you will now have a fileNameStr object containing your file name and a data object containing the contents of your file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding of what speeds you can achieve, I suggest you analyze this diagram http://www.scriptreactor.com/conn_interval-throughput.pdf It shows the achievable speeds as a function of connection interval. iOS does not give you such a fine grained control but this info is still valuable for you to calculate with.

Source: [Sending image file over Bluetooth 4.0 LE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476335/sending-image-file-over-bluetooth-4-0-le)